# Integral approach for infinite sum of $e^{-n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, summation

A while ago a posted this same problem, I have a different approach, just need a little help...

$$\displaystyle e^{-n} = \int_{0}^{e} -nx^{-(n+1)} \,dx$$

Originally, we had, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n}$

This is:

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{e} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -nx^{-(n+1)} \,dx$$

\begin{align}
S_1 &= -x^{-2}
\\S_2 &= -x^{-2} - 2x^{-3}
\\S_3 &= -x^{-2} - 2x^{-3} - 3x^{-4}
\\S_4 &= -x^{-2} - 2x^{-3} - 3x^{-4} - 4x^{-5}
\end{align}
If someone can help me find the sum, I can finish this problem.

Comment: Why don't you just use geometric series?

Comment: Its too simple. This is much more interesting

Comment: Your sum diverges for $|1/x| > 1$ or $1 > |x|$, but you're integrating over $[0,e]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to compute directly the sum:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N e^{-n} = e^{-1}\frac {1-e^{-N}}{1-e^{-1}}
$$

---

NB:
This comes from
\begin{align}(1-e^{-1})
\sum_{n=1}^N e^{-n}
&= \sum_{n=1}^N e^{-n}e^{-1} -  \sum_{n=1}^N e^{-n}
\\&= \sum_{n=2}^{N+1} e^{-n} -  \sum_{n=1}^N e^{-n}
\\&= e^{-1} - e^{-(N+1)}
\end{align}

Comment: How did you derive that?

Comment: @Amad27 see my edit.